# How to write into dBase tables using Ruby on OSX?

Tags: ruby, dbf, dbase

I found only read-only dBase gems (dbf) but without write support. ODBC could be an option but on OSX I didn't find any drivers available. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Didn't have any success in finding a gem . So I looked into another programming language and because the goal was to update the DBF content of a shapefile, I used Python with GDAL bindings to achieve that.  And it just works ! Here is a snippet, in case you ever need it: http://pastie.org/2758295

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/infused/dbf

Comment: Well, turns out that The Ruby dbf gem allows _only reading_ dbf files

Answer (score 0):

you can try [shp-ruby](https://github.com/spatialnetworks/shp-ruby), it's a native bindings for Shapelib, allow you to read/write Esri Shapefiles and xBase DBF files in Ruby.